# Why can't I use a boost::function in an Objective-C++ block?

Tags: c++, objective-c, block, objective-c++, boost-function

The following code throws an exception

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_function_call> >'
  what():  call to empty boost::function
```

at the line `f()` (while executing the block):

```
void foo(); // assume this is defined somewhere
boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&foo);

^(void) {
   f();
}();
```

However, according to [the documentation on blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Blocks.pdf),

> In general you can use C++ objects within a block. Within a member function, references to member variables and functions are via an implicitly imported this pointer and thus appear mutable. There are two considerations that apply if a block is copied:
>
> - If you have a __block storage class for what would have been a stack-based C++ object, then the usual copy constructor is used.
> - If you use any other C++ stack-based object from within a block, it must have a const copy constructor. The C++ object is then copied using that constructor.

This seems to be true normally; if I replace `f` above with an instance of a simple class with an `operator()()`, the above code runs as expected.

Why doesn't the version with `boost::function` work?

Comment: I'm no boost expert, but I'd hazard a guess that it relates to the *const copy constructor* for the `boost::function<>` type (per the quoted documentation).

Comment: Do you get the same error without the bind call (not needed for free functions, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#id1274976))?  What about using the portable syntax, function0<> instead of function<>?

Comment: I'm curious about the `bind()` call as well, unneeded and could be responsible for the error.

Comment: @academicRobot, @lefticus - there's no difference without the `bind()` call (and in my actual situation, I need to bind some parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if I modify the declaration with `__block`, it works correctly:

```
__block boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&foo);
```

I'm still not sure why this is - as @Richard mentions in a comment above, it must have to do with the "const copy constructor" as opposed to the "usual copy constructor". I don't know how to check this difference, though; the following works fine:

```
const boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&foo);
const boost::function<void()> g(f);
g();
```

and if that doesn't call a "const copy constructor", I'm not sure what will.

Answer (score 0):

The example in your answer,

```
const boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(&foo);
const boost::function<void()> g(f);
g();
```

works because you're calling `operator()` in the same scope in which its callee was created. `f()` would work outside of block scope as well, and calling `foo()` would work inside block scope because it is a classic function and is not considered to be "modified" when it is called. The referenced call to a *const copy constructor* is made when passing the object from containing scope to block scope. It would appear that whatever difference exists in the *const copy constructor* is failing to copy part of the object through to block scope.